# Android: How to programatically create multiple imagebutton views?

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I have over 30 clickable imagebutton views that I want to create programatically instead of using multiple xml files. Can someone please explain how I can do so? For each imagebutton, I need to:

1. be able to name and set the ID of each view programatically, like R.drawable.button01, R.drawable.button02, etc. since I would need to refer back to them later with findViewById().
2. each imagebutton is clickable and I have a button pressed down image for each button so I need to figure out how to assign the button press actions to each button dynamically instead of using a xml resource file for each.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any of the layout as root like Linear or Relative initialize it ..

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
ImageButton button =new ImageButton(context);
layout.addView(layout);
setContentView(layout);
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: this does not explain how to do 1 and 2.... I know how to create an imagebutton programatically but I want to be able to define and set the resource ID and define click action programatically...

Comment: To set id there is simply a function setId() which accepts integer as id and you can set click listener also .

Comment: OK. Thanks. This helps on the construction of the imagebuttons. But how about defining the button pressed image change? As mentioned, I do not want to use xml to define the button press andnormal state resource file for each button.

Comment: You can use isPressed() , setPressed method of buttons inherited from view class and set drawable according to your choice.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work. For those who are interested, here is my code:                                               `StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
         states.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_pressed},getResources().getDrawable(idNormal)); // Note the "-"
         states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},getResources().getDrawable(idClick));
         btnMapLoc.setImageDrawable(states);`

Answer (score 0):

A view has a function `setId()` that you can use to set an ID. You can use `setImageResource()` for the image

Answer (score 0):

For my project I am creating a dice game (Yahtzee) for school. For my buttons I added them in XML

```
<ImageButton
        android:id = "@+id/dice1"
        android:src = "@drawable/red_1_dice"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop = "60px"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "30px" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id = "@+id/dice2"
        android:src = "@drawable/red_2_dice"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "250px" 
        android:layout_marginTop = "-130px"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id = "@+id/dice3"
        android:src = "@drawable/red_3_dice"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "135px"
        android:layout_marginTop = "20px" />
```

then in my main i did this.

```
public class Z_veselinovic_yahtzeeActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ImageButton button1, button2, button3, button4, button5;
    Button start, reroll, hold;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Buttons();
    }


    public void Buttons()
    {


        button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.dice1);
        button2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.dice2);
        button3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.dice3);
        button4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.dice4);
        button5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.dice5);

        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);
        reroll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Reroll);
        hold = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Hold);

        reroll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        hold.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View whatever)
            {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), start.getText() + " Game", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Random rand1 = new Random();
                Random rand2 = new Random();
                Random rand3 = new Random();
                Random rand4 = new Random();
                Random rand5 = new Random();

                int dice_num_1 = rand1.nextInt(6) + 1;
                int dice_num_2 = rand2.nextInt(6) + 1;
                int dice_num_3 = rand3.nextInt(6) + 1;
                int dice_num_4 = rand4.nextInt(6) + 1;
                int dice_num_5 = rand5.nextInt(6) + 1;



                if(dice_num_1 == 1)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_1_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_1 == 2)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_2_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_1 == 3)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_3_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_1 == 4)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_4_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_1 == 5)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_5_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_1 == 6)
                {
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_6_dice);
                }




                if(dice_num_2 == 1)
                {
                    button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_1_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_2 == 2)
                {
                    button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_2_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_2 == 3)
                {
                    button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_3_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_2 == 4)
                {
                    button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_4_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_2 == 5)
                {
                    button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_5_dice);
                }

                else if(dice_num_2 == 6)
                {
                    button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_6_dice);
                }
```

I hope this helps.